# Merge values with missing Series Index with a main index

Tags: pandas

Say I have an index:

```
i = pd.Index(['apple', 'banana', 'orange'])
print(i)

Index(['apple', 'banana', 'orange'], dtype='object')
```

Now, I perform some groupby function and the result of the values is, `p`:

```
p = pd.Series({'apple' : 1})
print(p)

apple    1
dtype: int64
```

How do I merge this `p` Series, then `fillna(0)` with the index `i` to get:

```
apple     1
banana    0
orange    0
dtype: int64
```

There are ways like `merge` using a `df` but I'm thinking if this can be done directly with a `Series`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by index values and `fill_value=0` for replace missing values:

```
print (p.reindex(i, fill_value=0))
apple     1
banana    0
orange    0
dtype: int64
```